# How can I calculate the minimum of two numbers?

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I have a calculation sample/formula that outputs the site score mainly based on these parameters,

- Page Views
- Average Session Duration (Floating point number that is in minutes and seconds i.e. 1 minute 30 seconds would be 1.30.
- Top 3 Geolocations from which the website is most frequently visited and their percentages (e.g. (UK 30%, US 16%, Germany 10%).
- Site Revenue (Monthly Avg. Net)

This works fine in MS Excel.

Here's the calculation sample/formula

Now the thing is that I am trying to reproduce this exact formula into JavaScript code, and I am not that familiar with JavaScript Maths, plus some things from the calculation sample are slightly unclear to me.

Here's what I tried:

```
const siteEvaluationFormula = ((PageViews - 100000) / 750000 * AvgSessionDuration * (totalPercent * 60) + ... nothing after this I just gave up in confusion);
```

I'm stuck when it comes to calculating the minimum of two numbers. What do I use to calculate the minimum in JavaScript?

Comment: You are on the right track. After the`+` sign, you would be adding `Math.min(40,(siteRevenue/5000 * 40));`, But, the equation needs to start with `Math.min()` as well. Because the formula suggests you want the minimum of either `60` or your formula you've created. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

Comment: if you provide the inputs with the correct results it would be easy to demonstrate this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks, after your comment, I just looked up Math.min and found out what I was looking for.

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code.

Comment: @outis Oh I am sorry for that, this image was actually a real image sent by my client so I just straightforward included it.

Comment: @Stranger: while you shouldn't use an image for textual data, neither should you not post the formula. Questions should have a [mcve]. If the formula itself shouldn't be posted for client privacy, create another as part of a minimal example that includes the essentials.

Comment: @outis Oh, I asked my client before posting If I could share it with other developers on SO for some code conversion and he allowed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to complete your formula

```
const siteEvaluationFormula = Math.min(60, ((PageViews - 100000) / 750000 * AvgSessionDuration * (totalPercent * 60) + Math.min(40, SiteRevenue/5000*40));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually thought that the environment on StackOverflow would be a bit hostile for me like my senior devs told me but turn out, It's not that hostile at all.

Comment: aam... one question, how is my question not focused? why did someone close it? you and others just answered it. :(

Comment: Your question wasn't verry specific. Instead of asking us to "Complete the formula", maybe a better way to pose the question was to explicitly ask "How do i take the minimum of two values in javascript". However, i'm not sure :)

Comment: Oh ok I am sorry for that.

Comment: @Stranger - this: "_StackOverflow would be a bit hostile for me like my senior devs told me_" - SO can be hostile, but that is usually the result of people coming here and asking for homework solutions and other coding tasks without any effort whatsoever. SO has a culture of "try first - ask last".  [Here is a good explanation of expectations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341). So the volunteers here get frustrate when questions are more "gimme, gimme, gimme" rather than "here is what I've tried, this is how it failed, these are the error messages" etc.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh ok, now I get it. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: I think it's a bit too easy to blame the people who ask for homework solutions. StackOverflow can indeed be hostile and intimidating to newcomers, even to newcomers who come with great questions. At least once per week I see someone arrive with a great question, and before I've had time to answer, it gets deleted by the asker because of hostile comments.

Comment: On that topic, see also [stackoverflow.blog: What a very bad day at work taught me about building Stack Overflow’s community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/)